# Polymer: manually submitting a form

Tags: forms, submit, polymer-1.0, manual

In polymer I'm trying to manually submit a form. My form looks like this:

```
<form id="myForm" on-submit="{{ submitForm }}">
    <input class="text" value="{{ someValue}}">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And in the polymer object I have:

```
submitForm: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Whenever I try to do the following:

```
document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
```

the form totally ignores the on-submit attribute and posts the form to a new page.

I'm building a on-screen keyboard for anyone wondering why I would want to do this. I need to submit the form whenever someone hits the enter key on the on-screen keyboard.

Does anyone know why this happens?

A JSBin example to show you the exact problem (see the alerts): http://jsbin.com/wadihija/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.submit) about `submit`:

> The form's onsubmit event handler will not be triggered when invoking this 
>   method ... it is not guaranteed to be invoked by HTML user agents.

However, calling `click` on a `submit` type button seems to work. See here:

http://jsbin.com/tuxac/2/edit

Here is a modification of your jsbin that I believe does what you want:

http://jsbin.com/wadihija/6/edit

Comment: Thanks alot for your research! I've been so used to using jQuery for submitting forms that manually submitting a form seemed so default for me..

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://jsbin.com/nufanote/3/edit) along the lines of what you're trying to do? This is a result of a key feature of Shadow DOM: Encapsulation. The elements in your polymer-element's template are not in the main document, and as such, are not available via `document.getElementById()` and the like.

You could instead call `this.shadowRoot.getElementById()` and [it would work](http://jsbin.com/guxotevu/3/edit) because `this` inside of your polymer-element's prototype is linked to the host element. Or even better, take advantage of the amazing features Polymer gives you for free. Polymer exposes `this.$` to polymer-elements, which contains a key for every element in your template that has an ID! No method call needed, just use `this.$.myForm.submit()`. [Here's the final jsbin](http://jsbin.com/calubuno/2/edit).

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, the problem you are describing is not the problem i'm having. I've made a [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/wadihija/1/edit) showing you a simplified version of my problem. It's basicly manually submitting a form from a parent component.

Comment: Wow, that is really weird behavior. If I could upvote your question again I would :)