# Polymer paper-input and form submission

Tags: html, input, polymer, web-component

I'm working on a forum theme and started using web components but the form elements don't work.

I have stuff like this:

```
<input type="text" name="subject" maxlength="85" value="{$subject}" tabindex="1" />
```

and I tried translating it like that

```
<paper-input floatinglabel="" label="{$lang->thread_subject}" type="text" name="subject" maxlength="85" value="{$subject}" tabindex="1"></paper-input>
```

and all kind of variations also nesting the  element inside but it doesn't work.

Same goes for all other input elements like submit buttons, checkboxes etc.

Comment: Can you be more specific what doesn't work, or what errors you're getting?

Comment: Well, the form doesn't work. 
The first line (normal <input>) works just fine, the <paper-input> renders correctly and seems to do everything what it supposed to do but it doesn't do the form input so in this case it would say "You  didn't enter a subject". No paper-inputs work, I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24461460/polymer-form-post-data

Comment: I saw this before but I don't really get it.
I have to write a bunch of JS or what ? Just to do this simple thing ? And how to do submit paper-(ripple)-buttons ?

Comment: The problem is that `paper-input` wasn't originally meant to be used in a POST-based `<form>` workflow. It was made for Single-Page Applications. So yes, to get it to work with standard `<form>`s requires JS. I've heard unofficially that the Polymer team is working on a `<paper-forms>` element that will do this automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is this already usable?  https://github.com/PolymerLabs/paper-form

Answer (score 1):

For Polymer 1.0 see the new [Iron Form](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-form) element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this - http://jsbin.com/kurelaji/2/edit